# Laurent expansion of $\operatorname{sech}(z)$ centred at $\pi i/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have found that the roots of the $\cosh(z)=0$ occur at $\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}{2}$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}\cup{0}$. But I want to find the order the poles of $\operatorname{sech}(z)$ so I'm trying to find the order of the zero for just $\pi i/2$ and after that also the residue at  $\pi i/2$.
Thanks

Comment: The zeroes of $\cosh(z)$ are $z = \frac{i \pi}{2}(2k + 1)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Do you want the Laurent series around $z = i \pi/2$?

Comment: @A.P.  Ah yes I'm sorry that's what I meant- and yes please that's the Laurent expansion I need. And also the order of that particular zero- Ive edited it now

Comment: By CAS:  the residue is $-\mathrm{i}$.  I imagine one starts with $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \sinh z = \cosh z$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}z^n} \sinh z = (-\mathrm{i})^n \sinh\left( z+\frac{\mathrm{i}\pi n}{2} \right)$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}_{>0}$ to get the simplicity of the zeroes and this residue.  But I'm off to dinner, so won't be working out details.

Comment: @EricTowers CAS?

Comment: CAS = "Computer Algebra System".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laurent expansion is based on expanding

$$\operatorname{sech}{(\zeta+i \pi/2)} = -i \operatorname{csch}{\zeta} = \frac1{i \sinh{\zeta}}$$

for small $\zeta=z-i \pi/2$.  The result is

$$\frac{-i}{\zeta} \frac1{1+\zeta^2/3!+\zeta^4/5!+\cdots} = -\frac{i}{\zeta} +i \frac{\zeta}{6} - i \frac{7}{360} \zeta^3+\cdots$$

Higher order terms will require more algebra or a CAS.